# What type of connection is this to my spigot?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to replace an outside spigot. I have found where it comes into the house and I want to replace it with a new one. However, I am not sure how it's connected. I cannot tell if I will be able to unscrew or need to actually cut the copper pipe.

A plumber quoted me $200 to remove it and put a new one on. That seems really high to me.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do be sure that your spigot actually needs to be replaced. Many can be re-packed with new seals quite easily, and sometimes they just need the packing nut tightened to resolve leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like a factory-crimped assembly, all part of the frost-free spigot. It's designed to optionally allow a sweat (solder) joint, as you have with the street ell, or a threaded connection.

I'd de-solder the ell and start fresh from the length of pipe in the foreground. You could also clean up and reuse the elbow if your new spigot happens to have the exact same length and configuration.

Comment: Thanks! So you're recommending I cut the pipe right before the solder of the ell... then get a fresh ell and assemble it to new spigot, correct? Is it possible to get an ell that doesn't require soldering?

Comment: I suggested desoldering. It's up to you if you want to cut anything.

Comment: Sharkbite brand fittings are considered reliable and don't require soldering. I'm not sure whether they'll get you all the way through this project, though.

Comment: Thanks so much @isherwood, I really appreciate it. I didnt even consider the possibility that I may be able to fix existing spigot, I am going to try that first. Duh!